# How to assign XML data to the input type hidden value

Tags: jquery, html

Here I have small requirement, I'm getting alert with xml formated data. and the requirement is I have to assign all the xml data to the one hidden variable

Here is the hidden type

```
<input type="hidden" name="fileContent" id="fileContent1" value=""/>
```

Expected Result :

```
<input type="hidden" name="fileContent" id="fileContent1" value="<Rowsets><Rowset><Row><Line>101,abc,smith,1000</Line></Row></Rowset></Rowsets>"/>
```

JS code,

```
$("#saveImgID").click(function(){      
       var xmlStart =  "<Rowset>";
       var xmlEnd = "</Rowset>";
       var xmlString;
     var lines = $('#fileContent1').val().split(/\n/);
    var texts = []
     for (var i=1; i < lines.length; i++) {
             var countDelim = lines[i].split("#");      
     if (/\S/.test(lines[i])) {
                   texts.push($.trim(lines[i]));
         }

    }   

    xmlString = xmlStart;
     for (var i=0; i < texts.length; i++) {         
            xmlString += "<Row><Line>"+texts[i]+"</Line></Row>";
     }
 xmlString += xmlEnd;
xmlData = ""+xmlString;
$("#xmlDataID").val(xmlData);

$("#fileContent1").prop("value", "xmlData");
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the result of what you tried above?

Comment: Have you tried using `$("#fileContent1").val(xmlData);` ?

Comment: Yes... I tried $("#fileContent1").val(xmlData); , seems data is assigning to the variable but I didn't see in view source